# Webpack sass @import

Tags: node.js, sass, webpack

I'm getting an error/behavior that is quite strange and after several hours en various config trials i always end up with the same error below

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:
@import 'path/to/my/_partial.scss';
File to import not found or unreadable ...
```

Whenever i do a first run with 'npm run dev ' and the below configurations everything builds fine and all .scss files are compiled nicely into one .css file in the correct folder.
But when i modify or add some scss markup in one of the scss files the above error is thrown. But, and this is the strange part, when i save again without modifications the build passes again and in most cases the console does not show a build log but the css is rebuild correctly.
At first I was looking for wrong path configurations, but the first run builds correctly so the files are found... . I've been searching quite a while for a solution but didn't find anything,
Below my installed packages, webpack config and folder structure

**My installed packages are:**

```
"scripts": { "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack --watch" } 
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22" 
"resolve-url": "^0.2.1", 
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.1", 
"sass-loader": "^4.0.2", 
"style-loader": "^0.13.1", 
"css-loader": "^0.23.1", 
"node-sass": "^4.0.0", 
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4", 
"file-loader": "^0.9.0", 
"glob": "^7.1.1", 
"node-sass": "^4.0.0", 
"path": "^0.12.7",
 "postcss-cssnext": "^2.9.0", 
"postcss-import": "^9.0.0", 
"postcss-loader": "^1.2.1", 
"autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0"
```

**My webpack.config.js is quite simple and is as follows:**

```
entry: {
        styles: ['app.scss'],
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].css',
        path: __dirname + '/app/styles'
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'dev'),
            'node_modules'
        ],
        extensions: ['', '.css', '.scss', '.sass']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [

            // SASS
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
                    loader: "css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]!resolve-url!sass-loader?sourceMap"
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new extractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].css', allChunks: true })
    ]
}
```

he folder structure contains one app.scss file in the root ./dev from where alle other .scss files are included:

```
@import 'assets/styles/_variables.scss';
@import 'assets/styles/_mixins.scss';

@import 'assets/styles/_base.scss';
@import 'assets/styles/_motion.scss';

@import 'components/form/UiButton/_UiButton.scss';
@import 'components/router/UiSideBar/_SideBar.scss';
@import 'components/router/UiTopMenu/_TopMenu.scss';
@import 'components/router/UiSubMenu/_SubMenu.scss';
@import 'components/router/UiToolBar/_ToolBar.scss';
@import 'components/popup/UiModal/_UiModal.scss';
@import 'components/media/UiSpinner/_UiSpinner.scss';
```

so the first build always succeeds, the next builds throws an error like above mentioned but succeeds after double save without modifications.
Has anyone encountered this problem/behavior? Or is this a wrong configuration?